# css positioning difficulty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

Please forgive me for asking such a simple, my user name says it all. I'm having a slight problem with positioning the transparent background on my site: http://iamnatesmithen.com/bodyworks/index.php

I've noticed when i expand my screen, the transparent background which is nested in a carousel

```
.rslides {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: -151px;
    float: left;
    z-index: -1;
}
.rslides img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

for some reason #carousel-bg moves out of position within the media query call out of 1050px to 1600px. "If you expand your screen size beyond 1200px you'll notice #carousel-bg moves downwards"

Does any one know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you tell me what are you looking for exactly?

Comment: If you expand your screen size beyond 1200px you'll notice #carousel-bg moves downwards

Comment: ya that i have seen. What kind of out put are you looking for ? create a image and link it. so i can help you.

Comment: Sitting on top on that background will have content for the carousel. so it will be images and links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all do below things

Remove images that you have added as background image using img tag.
instead of that give background using css like

```
background-image: url("images/carousel-bg-1.png");
```

Comment: to add the image with the clouds will change when the carousel changes slide

Comment: for li   #rslides1_s0 { background-image: url("images/carousel-bg-1.png");
}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168437/css-positioning-issue-with-jquery-slider/12168899#comment16287795_12168899 @keyuratcodebins.com